# I can not find a way to click on a button using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I have a problem, I happen to have a button with these labels, I'm trying to click through Selenium but I can not find a way to click it. I tried to give it taking as reference the XPath, link text, and CSS selector but I do not achieve my goal. This is the code for the button:

```
<a class="btn btn-flat pull-right" data-action="export_report"> <i class = "icon-export"> </ i> Export </a>
```

East of the XPath:

```
// * [@ id = "reports"] / div [1] / div [2] / a
```

this selector:

```
#reports> div.span12> div.headline-action-block.pull-right> a
```

This is the button and my code in Python :(

**Button:**
[image: button]

**My code:**
[image: my code]

**I face this error**:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, I think that the page has a bot detector and it does not give me the exact path or id of the element I want to click on

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
openrate = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn")
openrate.click()
```

Assuming this is the only button, or the first button on the page. Otherwise `("a.btn.btn-flat.pull-right")`

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared it seems you have invoked `click()` in the previous step so in this step to `click()` on the button with text as **Export** you have to induce *WebDriverwait* for the element to be clickable and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies* :

- **PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT** :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  # lines of code     
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Export"))).click()
  ```
- **CSS_SELECTOR** :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  # lines of code     
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-flat.pull-right[data-action='export_report']>i.icon-export"))).click()
  ```
- **XPATH** :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  # lines of code     
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-flat pull-right' and @data-action='export_report']/i[@class='icon-export']"))).click()
  ```